# Can energy modulate gravity so that an engine may be constructed?

Tags: general-relativity

It is well-known from GR that adding to the kinetic energy of a mass increases the warping effect it has upon spacetime - i.e. KE gravitates. It is also known that potential energy (PE) does not gravitate. It is further known that a multiplicity of lossless systems may be constructed to continuously convert between KE and PE, and back again, without the addition of any external work (e.g. a lossless pendulum).

Could not then some sort of engine be constructed to exploit this effect? The basic idea is to pull when heavier and push when lighter, thus producing net motion in the "push" direction.

Answer (score 1):

Potential energy does indeed gravitate. In everyday contexts, the effect is far too small to directly detect, but the effect is real.

What you are proposing is a gravity-driven perpetual motion machine. The universe we inhabit is so structured as to make this impossible, regardless of how badly we might wish to believe otherwise.

Specifically: in our universe, there exists a quantity called energy, which can take a variety of different forms in different dynamical systems. It is an experimental observation that energy is a conserved quantity in interactions within those dynamical systems. This is mathematically true because the laws of physics which determine how those dynamical systems evolve do not have any time-dependence: they are just as valid yesterday as they will be tomorrow.

In your specific example, imagine that we could temporarily turn down gravity for an hour, lift a huge mass up, attach it to a machine with a cable, then turn gravity back up again and have the mass fall and drive the machine to perform work, etc., etc.

This requires that the laws determining how gravity works be time-dependent at will. That means that energy would not be conserved by such a system, and that in turn means that any such machine could not exist in our universe.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No, because potential energy *does* gravitate in General Relativity. *All* kinds of energy gravitate. (And not just energy... for example, pressure also produces gravity.)

As two specific examples, the negative gravitational potential energy binding the Earth together lowers its mass and its gravity, and the negative electrostatic potential energy binding a Hydrogen atom together lowers its mass and its gravity.